# Can't see all accounts in Experience cloud even after updating Sharing Settings

Tags: permissions, account, sharing, experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

I have an experience cloud set up with a CMS collection component to show all accounts in a particular view I set up. In Experience Builder I can see this CMS collection component populate with the expected Accounts.

I have a test user with the following credentials:

```
Role: Role1 (this is just a custom role)
User License: Customer Community Plus
Profile: Custom profile I cloned from Customer Community Plus
```

I went to Sharing Settings for Acconts and set up the following Account Sharing Rule:

```
Criteria: (Field search that should return all accounts)
Shared With: Portal Role: Role1
Account and Contract: Read Only
```

My assumption was after the above sharing rule was processed, if I logged into my Experience Cloud with this test user that I would be able to see all the accounts.

What I actually see is a blank screen where the accounts should be displayed (pointing to no accounts being shown for that view).

Am I misunderstanding the sharing settings? How can I allow this test user the option of viewing all the accounts in my CMS collection?

Comment: does the profile have read access to all fields of those objects included in the view?

Comment: When you say "Role1", this was auto-created by the system for this community account/contact/user, correct?  i.e. "[account name] Customer User"?